# Charge "something" over a 10 second interval then dump the charge on a load. (Alternative to battery?)

Tags: transistors, capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, charge, energy-harvesting

I'm getting a limited current of about 10 mA from a 12 V DC source.  I would like to charge "something" (anything but a battery) with this energy over 10 seconds, and then dump it to a 12V LED (70 mA) for a brief 0.5 second or shorter.  Then repeat.

Other than a battery, what else could be used to collect and hold this (10 mA) energy, and then be able to dump it after a 10 second time period?  A capacitor bank? I don't know.

To switch the circuit close/open, I could probably just use an NE555P chip.

Comment: There's no such thing as a 12V LED.  There may be 12V LED **strings**, or 12V LED **assemblies**, but not a single-diode 12 LED.  Please _edit your question_ to clarify what you mean when you say "12V LED".

Comment: Flywheel maybe? :-) Supercapacitor?

Comment: I have a solution in mind but you need to give more info: about the LED as TimWescott says, and especially about the source. What is it? What happens to it if you draw more than 10mA? Does voltage drop but the source is not harmed, or will it trip/overheat/break/anything else?

Answer (score 2):

10mA at 12V is 120mW.  120mW for ten seconds is 1.2 Joules.

The energy stored in a capacitor is equal to \$w = \frac {v^2} 2 C\$.  1.2 Joules stored in a capacitor charged to 12V works out to a bit less than \$16667 \mu \mathrm F\$ -- which is on the big side, but not unreasonable.  DigiKey currently has 63 different part numbers in stock for aluminum electrolytic capacitors between 18000 and 22000 uF, with voltage ratings between 16V to 25V.

Comment: The OP doesn't need 10mA at 12V for 10s but 70mA at 12V for 0.5s. Which makes 0.42J. 4700uF should be enough. Still a large cap.

Comment: I was going for an existence proof of a feasible answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a small supercapacitor of about 1F and 5.5V.

But to store and extract the energy you should use something like a LDO or buck converter to charge it up to 5V, and a boost converter to get the 12V from the capacitor discharging it from 5V down to 2V, or less.  Because the amount of energy available depends on the difference of voltage of the cap.

You should do all the calculations taking into account the capacity, the timing, the voltage range and current of the boost, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Batteries have rather constant voltage, which is convenient. Other forms of energy storage, like capacitors, do not. This complicates things because the charging/discharging circuit must have good efficiency over a wide range of capacitor voltage.

Energy stored in a cap is \$ E = CV^2 \$.

When capacitor voltage is close to zero, it is difficult to pull energy from it, because power at low voltage implies large current. However, wasting the first few volts only wastes a small fraction of the stored energy because voltage is squared. Thus capacitor energy storage usually means voltage on the cap never gets too low, and only the high fraction of capacitor voltage is used.

Here's an idea. This is not a finished circuit, but it's a starting point.

[image]

Comparator X1 and current sense resistor R9 form a hysteretic constant-current-input boost converter. R13 sets the input current. This charges C1 to a voltage higher than the input.

Comparator X2 monitors voltage on the charged capacitor and, when it reaches 24V, triggers a LED driver (not shown) which uses energy stored in the capacitor to light the LED. This comparator has hysteresis and turns off the LED when capacitor voltage reaches about 18V.

In a real circuit, C1 should be much larger to store enough energy to light the LED, same for C2.

If the LED does not light up and consume energy in C1, voltage will keep rising until the comparator's output transistor breaks down. Also if current is set too high, the comparator's output transistor, which is also used as the boost switch, will exceed its maximum current for a short time (the 10mA supply will limit current). I will leave the polishing as an "exercise to the reader".

Another implementation would use a comparator with hysteresis on the input voltage, controlling a boost LED driver which charges the cap with constant current. The idea is to have an input cap slowly charged by the low current 12V power supply. When it reaches 12V, enable the driver to charge the cap. This consumes more current than the supply can provide, so input voltage drops on the input cap. When it drops down to say 11V, stop the driver.

This would charge the output cap in pulses, and could be more efficient due to less switching, and better suited if the power supply can drop to lower currents than 10mA. In this case the LED will flash less often, but it will still flash.